# How to compare 2 sets of p-values?

Tags: p-value

I have 2 sets of p-values, each set containing 100 p-values from results of 2 different methods doing the same job. If I had only 1 p-value, I could have just basically said that the method achieving a smaller p-value is doing a better job. But with 100 p-values, I don't know how to interpret them. I know that it does not make sense to average the p-values, so I cannot compare the means of the 100 p-values for each set. So, my question is, is there a standardized method (a statistical test etc.) to compare 2 sets of p-values?

Comment: It is difficult to determine what these p-values *mean*, and that is of crucial importance. Unless you know (independently of the data) what the true effect size of each "job" is, then it's impossible to know how accurate the p-value is. It's certainly not the case that lower p-values are always better! Could you edit this post to provide more explanation of how these p-values were obtained and what they mean?

Comment: Yes, it isn't always true that a smaller p-value is better, but I was thinking when the settings are totally the same, I can compare success based on the p-values. I am not sure what an effect size is, but what I simply do is the following: I apply 2 clustering methods to the same data, and I get 100 clusters from each. Then I check the significance of the correlation of the center of each of the 200 clusters with a feature vector. I decided to use Fisher's method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method) to compute a single p-value for each method, and compare the resulting 2 p-values.

Comment: I don't see how you can justify such a comparison.  When there is no effect--when the null hypothesis is true--then a procedure that tends to produce smaller p-values with have too many false positive results.  That's bad. When the null is false, then of course it's good to have smaller p-values in general. But if you don't know in each case whether the null is true or false, all you have is a mess.

Comment: "*I could have just basically said that the method achieving a smaller p-value is doing a better job*" I don't see how that follows. p-value is not effect size.